# How to list R data frame variables in alphabetical order?

Tags: r

I can compactly display the structure of an arbitrary R object:

```
str(mtcars)
#> 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  11 variables:
#>  $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>  $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>  $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>  $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>  $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>  $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>  $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>  $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>  $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

How can I display these variables alphabetically, in a complete list? There doesn't seem to be any `alphabetical = TRUE` argument in `?str()` and I tried `order(str(mtcars))` to no success. The answer should output the following:

```
the_answer(str(mtcars))
#> 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  11 variables:
#>  $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
#>  $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>  $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>  $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
...
and so on
...
```

Comment: Using the top answer from the dupe, `str(mtcars[ , order(names(mtcars))])`

Comment: And here's the dplyr version `mtcars %>% select(sort(names(.), decreasing = FALSE)) %>% str()` or `mtcars %>% select(sort(names(.), decreasing = TRUE)) %>% str()` for descending.